# Como consultar un arreglo mediante uno de sus campos y mostrarlo en html

Tags: javascript, html, json, array

Tengo el siguiente **ARRAY**

```
var array = [
    {"productoId":"4","categoriaId":null,"marcaId":"2"},
    {"productoId":"87","categoriaId":null,"marcaId":"2"},
    {"productoId":"175","categoriaId":null,"marcaId":"20"}
]
```

Este lo recibo por medio de un **API** como documento `.json` de una página, ahora necesito saber los valores de cualquier producto mediante **javascript** y ponerlo en una tabla en **HTML**, es decir que si yo indico un código de producto `productoId` la rutina **javascript** lo busque en el **array** y me lo entregue para mostrarlo en la tabla **HTML**.

¿Cómo lo puedo realizar?

Comment: Hola Leidy, te recomiendo que visites el **[tour]** y que revises este enlace: **[ask]**

Comment: No termino de entender lo que quieres hacer. Si agregas los valores en una tabla ya te dice cuales son los Ids y demás datos.

Comment: pero lo que quiero es que mediante javascript yo le diga cual es la categoriaId (o cualquier otro) del producto X, y este me la muestre.porque es una inmensidad de productos los que hay, ese es solo un poco

Comment: Si lo que quieres es acceder a un elemento del json a través de productoId sería de esta forma `array[0].productoId` y ya con un ciclo buscas el Id que necesites.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con la explicación completa de qué es lo que quieres hacer. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: La respuesta de Jemonge responde bien a lo que pides, ahora, si quieres que se pueda buscar por cualquier (productId, categoriaId, marcaId) campo, debes seguir la misma lógica y sobre tu tabla agregar más inputs que busquen al producto según el campo específico.

Comment: hola @leidydianaarangomuñoz, bienvenida a **esSO**, te he dejado un ejemplo que permite recorrer el **array** y consultar por cualquier campo del mismo, inclusive el código esta diseñado para adaptarse en caso de que el **array** cambie, espero esto sirva a tus requerimientos, Saludos!! ;))...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo recorriendo el **array** recursivamente con un `for (in)`, lo interesante de este ejemplo que aquí te dejo es que puedes buscar por cualquier campo del **array**, ademas que se adapta a cualquier **JSON** sin importar su estructura, es decir, si el **JSON** llega a cambiar, esta función se ajustara a la nueva estructura sin tener que tocar el código.

Ejemplo:

```js
var array = [
    {"productoId":"4","categoriaId":null,"marcaId":"2"},
    {"productoId":"87","categoriaId":null,"marcaId":"2"},
    {"productoId":"175","categoriaId":null,"marcaId":"20"}
], item = [];

itemTitle(array);

function itemTitle(array) {
 for (n in array) {
  if (typeof array[n] == "object" && array[n] != null) {
   itemTitle(array[n]);
  } else if (!(n in item)) {
   item[n] = "ok";
   var opt = document.createElement("option");
   opt.text = n;
   document.getElementById("item").add(opt);
  };
 };
};
function initSearch() {
 document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML="";
 var x = document.getElementById("item"),
 item = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text,
 value = document.getElementById("search").value;
 search(array,item,value);
}
function search(array,item,value) {
 for (n in array) {
  if (n == item && array[n] == value) {
   display(array);
  } else {
   if (typeof array[n] == "object")
    search(array[n],item,value);
  };
 };
};
  
function display(array) {
 for (n in array) {
  var ul = document.createElement("ul");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var text = document.createTextNode(n+": "+array[n]);
  li.appendChild(text);
  ul.appendChild(li);
   document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(ul);     
 };
};
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Busqueda por</th>
  <th>Valor a Consultar</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><select id="item"></select></td>
  <td><input id="search" onChange="initSearch();"><button onClick="initSearch();">buscar</button></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<div id="myList"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo que puedes hacer es mantener los datos en el `array` y cuando necesites obtener algún dato lo buscas por el `productoId`.

Por ejemplo el siguiente código busca la categoría y la marca del producto que ingreses:

```js
var array = [
    {"productoId":"4","categoriaId":null,"marcaId":"2"},
    {"productoId":"87","categoriaId":null,"marcaId":"2"},
    {"productoId":"175","categoriaId":null,"marcaId":"20"}
]

function showProduct()
{
    var productId = document.getElementById("productId").value;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i].productoId == productId)
        {
            document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = array[i].categoriaId;
            document.getElementById("branch").innerHTML = array[i].marcaId;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
 ProductoID: <input type="text" id="productId" /> <input type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="showProduct()">
</div>
<hr>
<table>
    <tr><td>Marca</td><td id="branch"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Categoría</td><td id="category"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba haciendo esto

```
for (i in array) {
    var categoriaId = array[i].categoriaId;
    document.write(+categoriaId);
}
```

Saludos